# Is not valid integer value / Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Имеется полностью рабочий код.

```
function MySort(L: TStringList; ind1, ind2: integer): integer;
var i1, i2: integer;
begin
 i1 := StrToInt(L.ValueFromIndex[ind1]);
 i2 := StrToInt(L.ValueFromIndex[ind2]);
 if i1 = i2 then result := 0
  else if i1 > i2 then result := 1
        else result := -1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var L: TStringList;
begin
 L := TStringList.Create;
 L.Text := Memo1.Text;
 L.CustomSort(MySort);
 Memo2.Text := L.Text;
 L.Free;
end;
```

**Программа меняет все значения, со знаком (**=**), в порядке убывания:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А когда ввожу без знака ( = ) то возникает ошибка.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот вопрос: Как, место сообщения **Is not valid integer value** - Вывести свой текст. **К примеру, сообщение:** "Внимание, вы ввели неправильные - значения"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо проверяйте тип возбуждаемого исключения:

```
try
    L.CustomSort(MySort);
  except
    on E:EConvertError do ShowMessage('Ошибка, неправильно введены значения') // ошибка конвертации
    else raise; // прочие ошибки
end;
```

Либо контролируйте данные на этапе сортировки (или другом этапе):

```
function MySort(L: TStringList; ind1, ind2: integer): integer;
var i1, i2: integer;
begin
 if (not (TryStrToInt(L.ValueFromIndex[ind1], i1) and TryStrToInt(L.ValueFromIndex[ind2], i2))) or // Если не удалось конвертировать
  (i1 = i2) then // или результаты конвертаций равны, то
    result := 0
  else if i1 > i2 then result := 1
        else result := -1;
end;
```

В вашем примере возбуждать исключение вообще не вариант, так как оно прервет выполнение метода `Button2Click` и динамически созданный `TStringList` не уничтожится. Если вы не выполните этого в секции `except`. Ну или так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var L: TStringList;
begin
 L := TStringList.Create;
 try
   L.Text := Memo1.Text;
   try
     L.CustomSort(MySort);
   except
    ... обработка исключения ...
   end;
   Memo2.Text := L.Text;
 finally
   L.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решила, только что, таким способом:

```
try
  L.CustomSort(MySort);
  except
  ShowMessage('Ошибка, неправильно введены значения');
end;
```